# Laravel cron job runs in localhost but not in my shared hosting with cpanel

Tags: laravel, cron

I've to send automated emails to members of my subscription system. When I schedule a job in my laravel project and cron job on my localhost it runs properly every minute. But when I upload the same project to my shared hosting the scheduled task doesn't run. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

My CronTab:

```
SHELL="/bin/bash"
* * * * * php /home/tradiet1/public_html/tradiedemo/tradiepackage/artisan schdule:run
```

My NotifyMembershipRenewal:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Jobs\SendMembershipRenewalNotification;
use App\AppLog;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;

class NotifyMembershipRenewal extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'notify:membership_renewal';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send notification email to users informing them their membership subscription is about to expire  .';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $args = request()->server('argv');
        $log = new AppLog;
        $log->url = url()->current();
        $log->details = "Cron started at: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')." in dir: ".__DIR__;
        $log->details .= "\r\n".' args: '.json_encode($args);

        \DB::enableQueryLog();

        $now = Carbon::now();
        $expiryInDays = 7;
        $from = $now->addDays($expiryInDays-1)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $to = $now->addDay()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $users = User::with('membership')
            ->where('role', 3)
            ->whereBetween('membership_expiry', [$from, $to])
            ->get();

        foreach($users as $key => $user)
        {
            dispatch(new SendMembershipRenewalNotification($user, $expiryInDays));
        }

        $log->details .= "\r\n Count: ".$users->count();
        $log->details .= "\r\n ".json_encode(\DB::getQueryLog())."\r\n \r\n";
        $log->save();

        $this->info($log->details);
    }
}
```

My Kernel.php:

```
namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\AppLog;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        // 
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $log = new AppLog;
        $log->details = "Inside Kernel@schedule";
        $log->save();
        $schedule->command('notify:membership_renewal')
                 ->everyMinute() // 22:00 UTC = 08:00 AEST
                 ->appendOutputTo('./app_log.txt')
                 ->emailOutputTo(env('APP_LOG_EMAIL'));

        /*$schedule->command('inspire')
                 ->hourly();*/
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

My Crontab for localhost:

```
SHELL="/bin/bash"

* * * * * php /var/www/html/is/tradiedemo/tradiepackage/artisan schedule:run
```

My Crontab for my live shared hosting server

```
SHELL="/bin/bash"
* * * * * php /home/tradiet1/public_html/tradiedemo/tradiepackage/artisan schdule:run
```

The cron jobs run normally on my localhost and I get email every minute and log is stored in the DB as well as file. But when I transfer the project to my server the cron job runs every minute but the scheduled task doesn't run every minute. The task doesn't run even once.

Comment: See the `cron log`. I think its user related issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Shared Hosting you can't run a cron job every minute. because of it's a limitation on shared hosting(In Godaddy or Hostgator I guess). so you can do like run every 30 min every 15 min.

- You read it about here too [Cron Job in hostgator](https://www.easycron.com/support/i-am-using-hostgator-shared-hosting-they-have-cron-job-limit-which-doesnt-meet-my-need)
  But ya some Hosting provider provide this facility too.

So now the question is why it's not running right.

Its happened with me too. there is some issue with `register_argc_argv` but sometimes setting it `on` also not work so best practice rather than do it with PHP.

You can do this with `pho-cli` that's it.
Definitely it will work.

Do it like below

`SHELL="/bin/bash"
* * * * * php-cli -q /home/tradiet1/public_html/tradiedemo/tradiepackage/artisan schdule:run`

Hope it works for you.

**Update**

So as you said it does not work for you. so there is a rough solution for this is.
why not you do a cron on URL which is quite easy and work on any shared hosting and Cpanel things.

so for this, you can use `wget` for url. Below is the code related to it.

```
wget http://example.com/check
```

and now on your route function run your artisan programmatically something like below.

```
Route::get('/check', function () {
            Artisan::call('schedule:run');
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Regarding limitation of cron job frequency on shared hosting. I'm able to successfully run cron job every minute so I don't think that's an issue here. The main problem I faced is running the scheduled task inside the laravel project to be executed with my cron command. When I run php artisan schedule:run the task runs on my shared hosting server as well. It just won't run by my cron command. I tried using your suggestion by using php-cli -q as you suggested but it sends an error email to me saying: /bin/bash: php-cli: command not found

Comment: i guess  reason is server not default php-cli, so it's not run cron. You can change it to: " * * * * * /usr/bin/php-cli /path/to/project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 " . all we tring to do is running command through php-cli so you need to get the php-cli , otherwise you have to on it `register_argc_argv` . there is an roughlu solution too . but i dont want to use it. so please try this one . if its work thats perfect else will do roughly one

Comment: And don't use `bash` simply do it like this `* * * * * php-cli -q /home/tradiet1/public_html/tradiedemo/tradiepackage/artisan schdule:run` . dont add keyword `SHELL="/bin/bash"`

Comment: I tried every way you suggested but I'm still facing the same problem. My CronJob runs at scheduled time but the artisan command I scheduled to run doesn't get executed even once when the cron runs. I've been stuck on this problem for the last 4-5 days and its becoming frustrating. Have you ever faced this problem?

Comment: can you run cron with url like we normally do in core php. if yes thn make route and give that url route to cron and run your artisan programatically

Comment: Sadan TYSM. You finally helped me solve my issue. I had spent more than 20 hours of my work time over the past week trying to resolve this issue alone. I never thought laravel (or may be myself ;-) ) would suck so much at handling such a minor issue. BTW I used wget command to run my url at a scheduled time like this: wget -q -O /dev/null "https://example.com/membership/some-encrypted-key/notify-renewal" > /dev/null 2>&1 If you would not mind please update your answer and I would upvote it so that many others would not hvae to waste their vital working hours over such a minor issue.

Comment: Oh, that's great!  its work. Ya i updated my answer. Keep learning